# Check is string is in given format in C

Tags: c, format, scanf, buffer, stdin

I want to check if string is is this format `char,string,string,string`. I tried to use sscanf for getting the data and check it is in the format I want but it doesn't work.

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    char c1;
    char c2[1024];
    char c3[1024];
    char c4[1024];

    fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%c,%s,%s,%s", &c1, c2, c3, c4) == 4)
    {
        printf("true\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false\n");
    }
    
}
```

for example `^,oo,48,gg` should return true becaus it is in the format `char,string,string,string` but `&&,10,&h,***` will return false because it is in the format `string,string,string,string`

Comment: did you try the `sprintf` function ? `sprintf `will helps you to overcome this. see the man7 deiscreption here [sprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html)

Comment: seems like it works but can you explain why? what does %1023[^,] means

Comment: `%[` is the other string specifier of the `scanf`-family of functions, and it works by defining a set of characters that can be matched, for instance `%[abc]`will only match strings like "bcccaabc" and stop if it finds any other character. And you can invert the specifier behavior by placing the character `^` after the `[`, so `%[^,]`will match anything except for the character comma `,`, therefore being useful in your case to read a string between the commas.

Comment: is there a way to check for size_t,int?

Comment: I want to get from stding string in this format size_t,int. so now I tried to do
`(sscanf(buffer, "%1030[0-9],%1030[0-9]", c3, c4)` is that going to make sure the program will print true?

Answer (score 1):

`"%s"` matches any non-white-space sequence of characters, as long as there is at least 1.  It will scan through `"oo,48,gg"` as one string.

Instead use `"%[^,]"` to look for anything that is not a comma.

If only looking for a pattern match, not need to save the data, use `*` to scan, but not save.  Else use a width limit.

Consider the `fgets()` retains the `'\n'`

Use `"%n"` to scan the string offset scanned so far.

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(buffer, "%*c,%*[^,],%*[^,],%*[^,\n]%n", &n);
if (n > 0 && buffer[n] == '\n') {
    printf("true\n");
} else {
    printf("false\n");
}
```

---

`sscanf(buffer, "%c,%1023[^,],%1023[^,],%1023[^,]", &c1, c2, c3, c4) == 4` will accept  `"^,oo,48,gg,zzz"`.  IMO, an error.

Comment: i tried now to check if arg is an integer what i did was `%1030[0-9]` but when i insert for example 10.25 i get the ten what can i do to solve this

Comment: @user75453 The question had "Check is string is in given format ".  If you wanted to also parse and save the data, that is another question.  Best to put your true goals in a post.